# How to disable angular-translation warning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm getting all translation related warning in browser console, so i want to suppress/disable all related warning (Dont show to user)

## Warnings:

Translation for Department doesn't exist
a.(anonymous function) @ _bower.9144598….js:75
(anonymous) @ _bower.9144598….js:5
(anonymous) @ _bower.9144598….js:59
Z @ _bower.9144598….js:58
R.instant @ _bower.9144598….js:58
c @ _bower.9144598….js:59
fn @ VM673:4
(anonymous) @ _bower.9144598….js:5
$digest @ _bower.9144598….js:6
(anonymous) @ _bower.9144598….js:6
f @ _bower.9144598….js:4
(anonymous) @ _bower.9144598….js:4
d @ _bower.9144598….js:75

[image]

Comment: Provide the error (text) in your question instead of a screenshot, please.

Answer (score 1):

you can use useMissingTranslationHandler descriped as here 
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate'], function ($translateProvider) { // tell angular-translate to use your custom handler $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandler('myCustomHandlerFactory'); }); // define custom handler app.factory('myCustomHandlerFactory', function (dep1, dep2) { // has to return a function which gets a tranlation ID return function (translationID) { // do something with dep1 and dep2 }; });
```

Comment: Instead of modifying from bower folder, can we able to do from angular application side.

Comment: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/16_error-handling
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler
take a look at script.js in this pages